Is there a proper way to use multiple two column layout without messing up with heading?
I was making websites for a project before it hits the deadline in the next Monday, but when I inserted another heading the column keeps messing up because I have a 1080p monitor. I have no words to describe, so I'd appreciate if you want to solve this problem. Copy the entire snippet and modify the styling so I don't get confused. Image


    body {
      font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
      background: palegreen;
    }
    .wrap {
      display: flex;
    }
    .left {
      background: ForestGreen;
      flex-basis: 10%;
      padding: 10px;
    }
    .right {
      background: Honeydew;
      flex-basis: 90%;
      padding: 20px;
      height: 94vh; 
      overflow: auto;
    }
    .left2 {
    float: left;
    width: 45%;
    padding: 5px;
    }
    .right2 {
    float: left;
    width: 45%;
    padding: 5px;
    }
    .column1 {
      float: left;
      width: 45%; /* Adjusted width */
      padding: 10px;
      height:  650px;
    }
    ul.col2 {
      list-style-type: none;
      width: 600px;
    }
    h3.col2 {
      font: bold 20px/1.5 Helvetica, Verdana, sans-serif;
    }
    li.col2 img {
      float: left;
      margin: 0 15px 0 0;
    }
    li.col2 p {
      font: 200 Helvetica, Verdana, sans-serif;
    }
    li.col2 {
      padding: 10px;
      overflow: auto;
    }
    .row:after {
      content: "";
      display: table;
      clear: both;
    }
    a:link {
      color: LightGreen;
      background-color: transparent;
      text-decoration: none;
    }
    a:visited {
      color: LightGreen;
      background-color: transparent;
      text-decoration: none;
    }
    a:hover {
      color: YellowGreen;
      background-color: transparent;
      text-decoration: none;
    }
    a:active {
      color: DarkKhaki;
      background-color: transparent;
      text-decoration: none;
    }
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title></title>
  <style>

  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="wrap">
    <div class="left">
      <img src="" width="200" height="200">
      <a href="Site.html"><b><h1>Home</h1></b></a>
      <a href="About.html"><b><h1>About</h1></b></a>
      <a href="Elementary.html"><b><h1>Elementary</h1></b></a>
      <a href="JHS.html"><b><h1>Junior High School</h1></b></a>
      <a href="SHS.html"><b><h1>Senior High School</h1></b></a>
      <a href="CollegeCourses.html"><b><h1>College Courses</h1></b></a>
      <a href="ContactUs.html"><b><h1>Contact Us</h1></b></a>
    </div>
    <div class="right">
      <div style="height: 900px;">
        <img src="Images/3.jpg">
        <div><h1>Senior High School</h1></div>
        <p>This is the last school for students who
        are beginning to graduate and can finally express their new
        development and pursue their jobs or careers, ranging from eleventh
        to twelfth grade. Students who participated in senior high school
        are the age of sixteen to eighteen. Here are the strands listed
        below.</p>
        <div class="left2">
            <ul class="col2">
            <li class="col2">
              <img src="Images/Grade11.jpg" style="width:150px; height:150px;">
              <h3 class="col2">Grade 11</h3>
              <p>It is the first year of senior high school. Students
                in twelfth grade are usually sixteen to seventeen years old.
            </p>
            </li>
            </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="right2">
            <ul class="col2">
            <li class="col2">
              <img src="Images/Grade12.jpg" style="width:150px; height:150px;">
              <h3 class="col2">Grade 12</h3>
              <p>It is the second to last year of senior high school,
                and they are preparing for their graduation to pursue for colleges
                to learn. Students in twelfth grade are usually seventeen to
                eighteen years old.</p>
            </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div><h1>Academic Strands</h1></div>
          <div class="left2">
          <ul class="col2">
          <li class="col2">
            <img src="Images/ABM.jpg" style="width:150px; height:150px;">
            <h3 class="col2">ABM</h3>
            <p>This is known as Accountancy, Business, and Management. Those who
            want to participate ABM can learn about becoming an accountant,
            and those who want to compare statistics based on economics.
      </p>
          </li>
          <li class="col2">
            <img src="Images/HUMMS.png" style="width:150px; height:150px;">
            <h3 class="col2">HUMMS</h3>
            <p>This is known as Humanities and Social Sciences. Those who want
            to participate HUMMS can learn about the history, social studies,
            geography and much more.
      </p>
          </li>
          </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="right2">
          <ul class="col2">
          <li class="col2">
            <img src="Images/STEM.jpg" style="width:150px; height:150px;">
            <h3 class="col2">STEM</h3>
            <p>This is known as Sceince, Technology, Engineering, and Mathematics.
            Thos who want to particiapte STEM can learn about equating calculations,
            technology, and wanting to become a technician to play with.</p>
          </li>
          
          <li class="col2">
            <img src="Images/TVL.jpg" style="width:150px; height:150px;">
            <h3 class="col2">TVL</h3>
            <p>Also known as Technical Vocational Livelihood Track, these
            are one of the few strands to have multiple tracks for those
            who want to choose based on their priorities.</p>
          </li>
          </ul>
      </div>
        <div><h1>Technology Vocational Livelihood</h1></div>
        <h2>Home Economics</h2>
        <p>Students can learn how to support themselves and family
        around their lives. Here are the list of Home Economics tracks to
        discover:</p>
          <div class="left2">
          <ul class="col2">
          <li class="col2">
            <h3 class="col2">Housekeeping</h3>
            <p>For those who want to take apart of housekeeping, students
            can learn how to operate homes to keep the place tidy, depending on
            levels of maintenance.
      </p>
          </li>

          <li class="col2">
            <h3 class="col2">Food and Bevreges Services</h3>
            <p>People can discover about servicing in
            food and beverages to make sure that none of the food or drinks can be
            served spoiled.                
      </p>

      <li class="col2">
        <h3 class="col2">Bread & Pastry</h3>
        <p>Students can develop on learning how to prepare
        and produce bakery/pastry products, cakes and desserts. These can also
        prepare on making creative types of pastry and desserts based on
        the artist's creativity.
  </p>
      <li class="col2">
        <h3 class="col2">Local Tool Service</h3>
        <p>People can learn more about local tool services
        on our daily lives. Using the tools such as hammer, drill, and a saw
        can create or repair many products and buildings.
      </p>
          </li>
          </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="right2">
          <ul class="col2">
          <li class="col2">
            <h3 class="col2">Bartending</h3>
            <p>Students can learn about serving drinks and deliver them
            to the guests to keep them excited.</p>
          </li>
          
          <li class="col2">
            <h3 class="col2">Front Office Services</h3>
            <p>Students can now learn about initial contact
            between a customer and business. These are the services that are
            directly involved in the customer service process.</p>
          </li>

          <li class="col2">
            <h3 class="col2">Commercial Cooking</h3>
            <p>Students may develop to prepare of food for the
            greater public. It serves as a significant contributor to the economy
            by generating revenue, supporting small businesses, and driving tourism.</p>
          </li>

          <li class="col2">
            <h3 class="col2">Caregiving</h3>
            <p>Students now study about providing care for the daily needs
            of someone that is unable to care for themselves. The care my include
            addressing the physical and emotional needs of someone that requires
            continuous support and attention.</p>
          </li>
          </ul>
      </div>
      <h2>Information & Communication Technology</h2>
      <p>Students can learn how to
      program computers, reverse engineering, learning about components,
      and reparing gadgets whatever they succeed. Here are two lists
      of Information and Communication Technology tracks to discover:</p>
      <h1>Requirements</h1>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="column1" style="background-color:Khaki;">
          <h1>Grade 11</h1>
          <h4>STUDENTS FROM PUBLIC SCHOOLS</h4>
          <ul>
            <li>2 pcs. 2x2 ID picture(White Background)</li>
            <li>2 copies of birth certificate</li>
            <li>Original Certificate of Good moral character</li>
            <li>Original Form - 138 (Card with LRN)</li>
            <li>Copy of Certificate of Comlpetion</li>
          </ul>
          <h4>STUDENTS FROM PRIVATE SCHOOLS</h4>
          <ul>
            <li>2 pcs. 2x2 ID picture(White Background)</li>
            <li>2 copies of birth certificate</li>
            <li>Original Certificate of Good moral character</li>
            <li>Original Form - 138 (Card with LRN)</li>
            <li>Copy of Certificate of Comlpetion</li>
            <li>ESC Certification (System Generated From PEAC)</li>
          </ul>
          <h4>NON-ESC GRANTEES FROM PUBLIC SCHOOLS
              (APPLICANTS FOR VOUCHER PROGRAM)</h4>
          <ul>
            <li>2 pcs. 2x2 ID picture(White Background)</li>
            <li>2 copies of birth certificate</li>
            <li>Original Certificate of Good moral character</li>
            <li>Original Form - 138 (Card with LRN)</li>
            <li>Copy of Certificate of Comlpetion</li>
            <li>ESC Certification (System Generated From PEAC)</li>
            <li>Latest ITR (Income Tax Return) of Parent Gaurdian (if working)</li>
            <li>Certificate of Tax Exemption/Certificate of Indegency of Parent/
                Guardian from Municapal Office (if not working)</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="column1" style="background-color:Khaki;">
          <h1>Grade 12</h1>
          <ul>
            <li>2 pcs. 2x2 ID picture(White Background)</li>
            <li>2 copies of birth certificate</li>
            <li>Original Certificate of Good moral character</li>
            <li>Original Form - 138 (Card with LRN)</li>
            <li>Copy of Certificate of Comlpetion</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>



I tried everything but it didn't fix.
Here's what it's supposed to be. Image

Generally, avoid float to create your two columns. Look into using flexbox instead. However, the problem can be resolved by adding clear: both to the styling of the heading.

I thought of that styling but don't know where to put because it doesn't solve the same result. Could you copy the snippet and modify the CSS for cleanup? Thanks.

Use display: grid for this kind of layout. It is easy to handle.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_grid_layout
